# I can copy a file using cp, but trying to use sendfax returns cannot stat file.

Tags: cifs, cp, stat

As the title says, using Raspberry pi, and Raspbian, I am trying to configure a faxing server that basically reads a file from a CIFS share and sends it using hylafax. If the file is stored locally, it works, but if I try to access file directly from the share, I get "cannot stat file" error. If I try to copy the file using cp, it works, and stat  works as well. Tried changing permissions, but no help there. Any ideas?